# I upgraded ddev and now the web container won't start

Tags: php, ddev

I upgraded [ddev](http://ddev.readthedocs.io/) to v0.16.0 and now my web container won't start. It either fails the health check or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of v0.16.0 and v0.17.0, ddev has some maturing to do with regard to upgrades. Currently, each upgrade has been requiring a few things:

- Delete the project's .ddev/docker-compose.yaml
- Re-run `ddev config` or delete the "webimage" and "dbimage" lines in .ddev/config.yaml
- If you have made customizations to your nginx config, remove those from the .ddev folder and recreate them as suggested in the [release notes](https://github.com/drud/ddev/releases/tag/v0.16.0).

Full details are in the [release notes](https://github.com/drud/ddev/releases/tag/v0.16.0).